# Solr title search failing

Tags: search, solr, title

I am indexing the title field for few products in Solr.

But when I am searching, I am not getting those titles in response.

For eg. I am storing following as title : Baboons Typing Tshirt

But when I am searching following I am not getting any result !!!

1)title:Baboons
2)title:(Baboons Typing Tshirt)
3)title:(Baboons*)

On the otherhand, if I am searching like this, I am getting lot of results

1)title:(Tshirt)

I have indexed many titles containing word Tshirt but I want to search a specific title which is failing..!!

I dont know whether Solr is ignoring first words, or it is doing something random.

My Question is basically: If  I have a search title with lots of words, I will like to match it with the title which contains maximum common terms.

How to do it?

Thanks

Comment: It is very difficult to help you without looking at your config. Post the relavant parts of your schema.xml. Also include details about how you are doing the query — are you using the StandardQueryParser or the DismaxQueryParser, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Solr works like that by itself. You don't have to change anything.
You have to be careful how you set up your fields in schema.xml, i.e. how analysis is done.

You can use `Solr's admin > Analysis` interface to see how exactly your title field (when indexing) and query (when searching) is processed (tokenized, transformed).

Remember, match, in order to occur, requires identical word (case and everything) on both sides (index & query).

To open your index and see how Solr has actually indexed your data, use [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/).